# 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, path, pip

I'm trying to install Tweepy using pip, but I keep getting this as the response:
[image]

I've seen similar problems and people always suggest adding C:\Python34\Scripts to your PATH. Here is what happens when I try and do that:
[image]

Then when I do echo %PATH% it doesn't show the path that I added. Using pip still does not work.

How do I make it to where I am able to use pip? I looked through multiple other questions that were VERY similar to mine, but none of the solutions worked.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: looks like youre using windows so ensure that you've [installed `pip`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: Is C:\Python34 actually your Python directory?  Depending on what version how you installed and how, it might be something else.

Comment: Yes, my directory is C:\Python34. I double checked just in case.

Comment: I think that "WARNING" is probably the main issue here.  How long is the PATH variable exactly?  If it is in fact longer than 1024 characters, you'll want to check http://superuser.com/questions/387619/overcoming-the-1024-character-limit-with-setx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using this guide for adding a new folder to your system path, normally works for me. It goes through a GUI instead of adding through the command line.

http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path

A second solution is that you can just cd into the directory that contains pip and use it from there each time, but thats only if nothing else works.

Comment: THIS WORKED. I LOVE YOU. THANK YOU. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using windows so you need to download the `get-pip.py` and run like this.

`Path_to_your_Python.exe\python.exe Path_to_get-pip.py\get-pip.py tweepy`

Here is the link for download [get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Comment: Python 3.4 ships with [pip included](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html)

Comment: Yes 3.4 has pip, I just can't seem to use it :(

Comment: @MoreFoam You have to mention the path towards the `python.exe` file. `Path_to_your_Python.exe\python.exe Path_to_get-pip.py\get-pip.py tweepy`