# Anaconda Packages

Tags: cmd, anaconda, package

I have Anaconda installed on my computer but when I type a command in cmd I only get 'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. What could be the problem? It's the same with pip.

[I can see that it is installed in my settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vtai.jpg)

Comment: It's your PATH environment variable. I don't know of a duplicate for Anaconda specifically, but it's the same problem and solution as [this PIP question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37710662/478656) or [this Java question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7709041/478656) or [this Python question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17953124/478656)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Anaconda should have added jupyter to your PATH automatically during the install if you selected that option as shown in the installation video, if you did not select it, you need to do this manually, here are the steps to do so:

1)go to mu cpmuter properties and click on **ADVANCE SYSTEM SETTINGS**

2)Select the Advanced tab.

3)Click the **Environment Variables button**.

4)Under **System Variables**, *select Path*, then **click Edit**.
You'll see a list of folders, as this example for my system shows something like:

C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;

You will notice that each of these file paths are separated by a semicolon ;
You can add additional folders that you want to include in searches. In this case, you need to add Anaconda to your path, it will be something like: C:\Users\myusername\Anaconda2
Add that to the list, **make sure your spacing is correct**
You'll need to restart the processes (e.g., command prompt) that use the system path to see the added folders.

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------## YOU CAN ALSO AVOID THIS MANUAL PROCESS ##

ANOTHER METHOD is reinstall this and while doing this make sure of thing that is shown in the scr shot below

while installing the anaconda the dialogue box appears giving two options

1. add anaconda to my path enviorment variable

   2. register anaconda as my default python version

***select both of this options though system will not recommend this but you have to mark***

thankyou!!
all the best!!

Comment: This stops making sense after "make sure your spacing is correct"

Answer (score 0):

Open your Anaconda Prompt instead of just your command prompt. Then type "conda list," you should get the correct output. I suspect that you did not add Anaconda to your PATH during installation and that's why your regular command prompt won't recognize the conda commands.

Answer (score 0):

Find where you anaconda is installed. Usually, it is under %USERPROFILE%\AppData.... You can set path using SETX PATH on CMD. e.g. I have installed anaconda3. It was installed in its default path.

e.g.

```
SETX PATH “%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3; %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts”
```

If you do not know where anaconda was installed, you can open "Anaconda prompt" app. You can see the environment path to your anaconda [You can find "Anaconda prompt" using Search Windows.